# Is there a way to cancel an auction in the auction house, or change the buyout price?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to put more items for sale in the auction house, but I have already reached the limit of 10. Is there a way to end current auctions early, or change the buyout price to sell the items currently being sold quicker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Edit: Updated for 1.0.4

You can cancel any auction, **so long as no bids have been made on it yet**.

If you want to change the buyout price, you will need to cancel the auction (assuming no current bids), and re-list it with the new starting/buyout prices).

*The ability to cancel auctions with no bids was added in patch 1.0.4.  Prior to that, the following historical answer was valid:*

You have 5 minutes from the start of the auction to cancel it.  Once you are past that 5 minute mark, there is no way to end the auction early, short of someone purchasing the item via buyout.

You cannot change the minimum bid or buyout price once the auction is started.

Your only options are to wait and see if someone buys it, or possibly give someone else (that you trust!) the money for the buyout, have them buy it, give it back to you, and put it back on the AH at a new price.  Keep in mind that you will wind up losing money this way to the AH fees, however.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is actually a way to cancel auction early. What you need to do is have the auctions page open showing the current auctions you have posted up. Then you need to go to your system tray in the bottom right and double click the time. From here go to the calendar and set the day back roughly 2 days. Once you apply this change you should see your auctions allow you to cancel them right away.

Comment: This is correct, I just tried this and it worked for me.

Comment: Attempting to cancel an auction via this method results in an error.

Comment: The last patch broke this method.

Answer (score 2):

As of the 1.04 patch on 8/21/2012, it is possible to cancel an auction at any time if no bids have been placed on it.  Once a bid is placed, the auction cannot be cancelled and you have to wait for it to end or for the buyout price to be paid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to cancel your auction once the first minutes are over. My guess it's so you don't abuse the auction house and get "new slots" (cap of 10 auctions) for free or see your item will only sell for less than expected. It's to prevent abuse.

You can not change the buyout price either while the auction is still running. Same reason, you could edit the buyout once you see high demand and it would be terrible for the whole system.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking about canceling an auction, and the question you linked is addressing canceling a bid. While it is the same answer (no, you can't), the concepts are rather different.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right... gonna edit that out to not confuse people >.<